# Lap Time Simulator Car (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, simulation

I'm currently trying to make a lap time simulator for point mass acceleration of a car. I've made a model for the engine and its speed as shown below. However I'm coming across a problem where the rpm(engine_speed) doesn't drop down once it's above 14000 where there would be a gear change. How can I improve this

```
car.torque = [4 7 10 12.5 14.5 25 30.5 30.5 35.5 45.6 44.8 39.4 33.8 34 13 4];
car.engine_speed = [1 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 8000 9000 10000 11000 12000 13000 14000 15000] .* 2 * pi / 60;
car.torque_spline = spline(car.engine_speed, car.torque);

%This is within a while loop
    model.wheel_speed = model.vx(idx-1) ./ car.wheel_radius;
    model.engine_speed = model.wheel_speed .* (car.gearbox .* car.gear_ratio);
    model.engine_speed = min(14000 * (2 * pi / 60), max(0, model.engine_speed));
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet, it appears that as wheel_speed increases, engine_speed can only decrease if gear_ratio or gear_box change.  Where are the gear variables set or modeled?

comment: I don't think you need .* or ./ in lines 2 or 4.  .* and ./ are only required when multiplying/dividing arrays element-wise.  In this case you're multiplying/divding each element of an array by a number.